# Website not shown as result on google search

Tags: seo

I made a website that went online 3 months ago. Wen it went online i've a**dded it to webmaster and added the url to google** on [this link](http://www.google.nl/intl/nl/add_url.html). Every page 
has a unique title and the following meta tags.

- Keywords
- Description

I removed the robots.txt to be 100% sure there wasn't an error in there. I've checked my logs on the server and can't find any errors that points to downtime or other errors. From websmaster **i've crawled the website successfully and there are no errors given**. The website has a 'unique' name and there aren't many related titles. the only way I find the website on google is by googling the full url. Why isn't the website in the results and what can I do about it?

when searching in google with site:mydomain.com i can see it's indexed.

There are **no crawl errors** and i checked all the options on the answer from the question that is marked as duplicated.

Comment: in the webmaster tools, what does it show for pages that are indexed? Are there any stats showing hits via search results?

Comment: @moudey pages are indexed but no hits

Comment: zero hits? I would resubmit again in case you made a mistake before, search results are influences by other sites linking into it so add it to other search engines and directories, a related google plus account that links to it does seem to help thinks get found. Adding structred data via schema.org (to the home page) will also improve hits. Google's logs should show "position" for each search term, so search for a phrase on the page and see what comes up? Meta tags like description are important in ranking.

Comment: @mousey sorry not zero i counted 3 hits in total. I tried indexing pages seperate too.

Comment: 3 hits is still hits, so it is working, look into SEO optimization and the SEO tag here for information on how to improve ranking, also a sitemap can help a lot

Comment: @mousey i did i added all the above meta tags and a sitemap. I have some unique keywords that are very uncommon  on google search barely any related results. I followed all official seo rules by google and did some projects before that are top results by google even on often used keywords.

Comment: since it actually gives you 3 hits via the search engine you can see that it is being indexed, so the original question is resolved. Why the SEO changes have not raised it in the rankings is a mystery.

Comment: The url is bodyprocess.nl you can check the meta tags there if you like. Thanks for the help.

Comment: can you raise a separate question - it might be best on stackoverflow since your code has issues- facebook has issues with your opengraph tags, you are incorrectly using `cite=` and `blockquote` site, the HTML doesn't validate including issues with links in the menu, if robots are seeing this it may affect your hits.  I would suggest turning on sitelinks too - given your domain name that should give you many more hits

Comment: @Mousey how do you find these errors? i have no errors in console or whatsoever. Where should i use blockqueot isnt it used for Quotes?

Comment: `<blockquote>` for a link not a text quote, facebook has (possibly the best) opengraph tags validator - which tells me you have had over 50 shares on facebook but that it had to guess at the tags, plus there are many articles on SEO and key meta tags to include. Places to start: Facebook opengraph debugger, http://validator.w3.org/nu (for HTML validation) and lookup `rel=author` and `rel=publisher` I'd also suggest a g+ page linked in with verified domain name (google ranks them higher). [Google Sitelinks](http://developers.google.com/structured-data/slsb-overview) will help